# How to divide the alphabet into lists of letters in a different way

Tags: python, list, divide

I should divide the alphabet into lists of letters. I done that, my solution is good but my mentor said to me that I should a little improve this solution.

This is my code:

```
import string
import random


def generate_list():

    list_of_letters=list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    number_of_letter = len(list_of_letters)
    main_list = []

    while number_of_letter > 0:
        a = random.randint(4, 7)
        number_of_letter -= a
        main_list.append(list_of_letters[0:a])
        del list_of_letters[0:a]

    print(main_list)

generate_list()
```

My mentor said me that I should take and remove lists of letters in one function, not to manually delete these pieces with lists of all letters manually using the `del function` So he would like to replace this fragment of code in one line.

```
main_list.append(list_of_letters[0:a])
del list_of_letters[0:a]
```

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pop()` function of lists. It returns one item of the list and removes it from the list.

As it removes from the right side, in your case you have to specifically tell to take the list item at index `0` by calling `pop(0)`.

So replacing your two lines from above with the following snippet should do everything in one step:

```
main_list.append([list_of_letters.pop(0) for _ in range(min(len(list_of_letters), a))])
```

Please note, that I stop popping elements from `list_of_letters` if `a` is larger then the remaining items in it, hence the `min(len(list_of_letters), a)`.